# Debian Stanalone Installation

Tags: installation, debian

I am trying to install Debian in a system that does not have any network connection at the time of installation. Is there any way to do so rather than ordering a DVD from Debian vendors? Is there any specific ISO file that I could install from without the internet on the destination computer.

Answer (score 0):

Debian has several installation methods, the most common are to install the `ISO DVD` that contains a desktop environment (the one you like), along with all the basic packages. Another installation method for systems that you are going to use as servers or similar, is the `netinstall` installation. You do not need to have an internet connection to install Debian, after installed, you can connect it, configure the repositories and then start installing the packages you need. At the following URL you can find various ISOs for each processor architecture.

```
https://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/
```